# What are the limitations of sonarqube rules (particularly for PL/SQL)?

Tags: xpath, sonarqube

I wonder if there are rules that I can not check with SonarQube's XPath rules ([the only possibility available for PL/SQL checking](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Adding+Coding+Rules)).

For example, would it be possible to check for dependencies between elements in the database schema (e.g. the fact that a view is using another view could be considered as a dependency between two views, is it possible to write a rule in XPath to detect that?)?

I am not an XPath expert. But I see that there is no "dependence checking" rule in the [144 rules proposed](http://dist.sonarsource.com/reports/coverage/rules_in_plsql.html), so I wonder if it is because of a limitation of XPath queries on the AST or not.

For the more general question, does anyone already failed to write a rule for any language because of the limitations of the API provided by SonarQube (both XPath and Java API)?

Thanks in advance for the answer,

Julien

Comment: I'm looking at your question from an XPath rules point of view, knowing nothing about PL/SQL. Can you show an example of an AST where dependencies between views would be checked for? In general: sure, XPath has its limitations (and SonarQube seems to be limited to XPath 1.0, which is more limited than 2.0 or 3.0). It's more flexible than DTD or Schema, but less powerful than Schematron, for example. For a more specific answer, you'll need to give specific cases.

Comment: You should contact support for questions about commercial products.

Comment: @LarsH, I do not have any example of AST since it depends on SonarQube and I do not have this product at the moment...

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam, ok so I will contact the support by mail, I thought I had to ask here when I looked at the [support page](http://www.sonarqube.org/get-support/) of SonarQube website.